# Disable automatic calculation of Detail amount (totallineitemamount) of Opportunities in Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online

I want to disable the automatic calculation of Detail amount in Opportunities in Dynamics CRM

[image]

I tried disabling all processes associated with Opportunity but it didn't work. I also checked the javascripts in the form, but none seem to alter its value on save

I also checked the field type and its not calculated

[image]

Below is a screenshot of entity details page

[image]

Comment: check if it is a calculated field

Comment: yeah I checked that, its a currency field and type is simple
added this detail to question

Comment: It can be also, plugin. In any case you can create your own field and hide this one. Copy calculated data on WF just to keep stuff consistent, nad WF as async job will be executed later than everything else, to be sure you can add a wait step to a WF

Comment: I thought there was a system setting to disable OOB calculations.

Comment: Try to implement plugin which overrides value with PreInsideTransaction scope. It is possible, that value is calculated before, and that you'll be able to change it.

Comment: @Daryl yes there is a setting, but it disables all OOB calculation across all entities like Quotes, discount, total and much more
I want to disable only this particular field as I need to use all other calculations like discount etc

Answer (score 1):

I checked and don't see any plugin that would enable us to turn off the automatic calculation.
I'm familiar with the challenges these calculations can raise. I once had a client that had an invoice with over 20,000 lines. Invoice auto-calculation uses the same mechanism in the system as Opportunity calculation.

With the addition of each line, the total amount recalculated. It was like climbing a mountain that got steeper with each step. Our normal invoice automation was timing out. I eventually wrote a console app to add the invoice lines.

One option would be to create a custom Opportunity line entity and do the calculations yourself.

Comment: If we create a new opportunity line entity, would that reflect in the Quotes as well?

Comment: You could create an N:1 relationship from that entity to the Quote entity too. Of course you will be losing all the OOB functionality on Opp and Quote lines, so proceed with caution. I would consider this to be a "last resort" type of idea. It would be better to continue to use the OOB line entities if you can figure out a way to make them work. Why do you want to disable the automatic calculation?

Comment: I want to calculate the total based on resource bookings

Comment: Then you might want to create a separate total field, like "Total Bookings", add an Opportunity lookup on the resources bookings entity (if that's possible), and then use OOB rollups or a custom rollup plugin to calculate.